Understanding the MQTT Sparkplug B specification
I am new to Sparkplug and I am studying the specification. I am confused about a few points. If anyone can clarify, I would be grateful.  If this is the wrong place to post this question, please kindly direct me to the right community.

When a new EoN device comes online, it is required to send out a
NBIRTH message. The specification states [pg 21] that this
message must be sent with "retain = false". With this being the case,
if a Host Application either comes online or reconnects after the EoN
device sends this message, how will that Host learn about the EoN's existence?
Even if subscribed to the topic, since the NBIRTH message is not
retained, the Host would not receive it.

The spec states [pg 21] "the NBIRTH MUST include every metric the
Edge Node will ever report on." Does this mean that all device
metrics must also be included (i.e. ones that will be later reported
by DDATA), or does this only refer to EoN metrics (i.e. EoN health,
status, etc)?

When is it appropriate to send a NDATA vs. DDATA from an EoN device?
Examples show NDATA including individual process metrics such as
individual sensor values. However, I can't tell if NDATA
should only ever provide metrics that apply to the EoN device itself
(i.e. device health, status, etc), and DDATA should be
used to convey individual device metrics (i.e. process data).

Since all DDATA messages are sent with "retain = false" [see page
32], how can newly joined Hosts see device values without waiting for the EoN to send a new DDATA upon data change? Sometimes a process data will not change for hours or days, thus newly connected Hosts would never see any value for it?  Or will Hosts be
sending new requests to learn about all EoN and connected devices
when the Host connects to the broker?  If so, what do these requests look like?


